# Autocomplete with readline in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, readline

I'm trying to use this nifty trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821661/how-to-code-autocompletion-in-python) to work with a csv file.  I can't seem to get autocomplete working in python3 though.  I don't know where to begin with readline.  The documentation was a little dense.  My guess is that I'm missing something without `raw_input()` from Python 2.

I've pasted my attempt below.  When I'm in the shell and I hit tab, I just get big tabs and no autocomplete action.  My intention is that the input statement below auto-completes on the strings `['10/10/2013', '10/13/2013', '10/14/2013', '10/15/2013']`.

What am I missing?

```
import readline

class MyCompleter(object):  # Custom completer

    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = sorted(options)

    def complete(self, text, state):
        if state == 0:  # on first trigger, build possible matches
            if text:  # cache matches (entries that start with entered text)
                self.matches = [s for s in self.options
                                    if s and s.startswith(text)]
            else:  # no text entered, all matches possible
                self.matches = self.options[:]

        # return match indexed by state
        try:
            return self.matches[state]
        except IndexError:
            return None


dates = [
    '10/10/2013 13:03:51',
    '10/10/2013 13:54:32',
    '10/10/2013 18:48:48',
    '10/10/2013 19:13:00',
    '10/13/2013 12:58:17',
    '10/13/2013 13:38:15',
    '10/13/2013 16:48:58',
    '10/13/2013 17:23:59',
    '10/13/2013 20:09:56',
    '10/13/2013 21:54:14',
    '10/13/2013 21:57:43',
    '10/13/2013 22:47:40',
    '10/14/2013 13:32:53',
    '10/14/2013 21:14:51',
    '10/15/2013 10:18:23'
    ]

dates = [x.split(' ')[0] for x in dates]

completer = MyCompleter(list(set(dates)))
readline.set_completer(completer.complete)
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
date = input('Enter a date in m/d/yy format\n\t')
```

Update: Nice answer below, but still broken for me on OS X.  I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting that.  I get autocomplete with this on Ubuntu, but it's not binding to `tab` on my OS X system somehow.

Comment: Your sample code works for me with **Python 3.3** albiet not very well. There are a few flaws with your ``Completer()`` I think :)

Comment: Yikes, it sounds like you're getting further than me.  I'm on OS X, Python 3.3...

Comment: Same here! :) I'm trying to fix your displaying of matched options. But I might have to leave this to someone else. I've done this successfully. See: https://bitbucket.org/prologic/mio-lang/src/tip/mio/state.py

Comment: Thanks for the answer below.  There's definitely something wrong with my OS X environment.

Comment: Did you ``brew install python3`` ? :)

Comment: Nope, downloaded from python.org

Comment: @mrKelley did you solve the issue with OSX?

Comment: There is a bug in that set_completer should not be given a method from a class (unless its a static method).    the method should be called with text and state.  there will be no self value (actually, I am guessing it will go with assigning text to self and state to text on the call.  or I am misreading the documentaiton

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Corrected version:**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import readline
from os import environ


class MyCompleter(object):  # Custom completer

    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = sorted(options)

    def complete(self, text, state):
        if state == 0:  # on first trigger, build possible matches
            if not text:
                self.matches = self.options[:]
            else:
                self.matches = [s for s in self.options
                                if s and s.startswith(text)]

        # return match indexed by state
        try:
            return self.matches[state]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def display_matches(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
        line_buffer = readline.get_line_buffer()
        columns = environ.get("COLUMNS", 80)

        print()

        tpl = "{:<" + str(int(max(map(len, matches)) * 1.2)) + "}"

        buffer = ""
        for match in matches:
            match = tpl.format(match[len(substitution):])
            if len(buffer + match) > columns:
                print(buffer)
                buffer = ""
            buffer += match

        if buffer:
            print(buffer)

        print("> ", end="")
        print(line_buffer, end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()


dates = [
    '10/10/2013 13:03:51',
    '10/10/2013 13:54:32',
    '10/10/2013 18:48:48',
    '10/10/2013 19:13:00',
    '10/13/2013 12:58:17',
    '10/13/2013 13:38:15',
    '10/13/2013 16:48:58',
    '10/13/2013 17:23:59',
    '10/13/2013 20:09:56',
    '10/13/2013 21:54:14',
    '10/13/2013 21:57:43',
    '10/13/2013 22:47:40',
    '10/14/2013 13:32:53',
    '10/14/2013 21:14:51',
    '10/15/2013 10:18:23'
    ]

dates = [x.split(' ')[0] for x in dates]

completer = MyCompleter(list(set(dates)))
readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n;')
readline.set_completer(completer.complete)
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
readline.set_completion_display_matches_hook(completer.display_matches)
print('Enter a date in m/d/yy format\n\t')
date = input("> ")
```

**Note(s):**

- Added a custom `display_matches()` (*may not be useful for you*)
- Added `readline.set_completer_delims()` call because we want to treat `/` as part of a word.

*Tested on Python-3.3 on Mac OS X*

Comment: Alright, there's definitely something wrong with my system.  This is working for me on Ubuntu, but I just get actual tabs on OS X.  Thanks for the clean-up.

Comment: Why did you use `sys.stdout.flush()` instead of adding `flush=True` to the last `print` statement?

Comment: seems like the method passed to set_completer  should either be class static method or regular function that is not part of a class definition.

Comment: I typed `10` and then pressing `tab` does not complete anything...instead it actually prints the tab.. and the cursor moves forward without any completion. I'm using Mac M1.