# Autocomplete the field in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, openerp-7

I have a field called 'name' the data which are entered in 'name' are going to the database. Whenever i want to enter a new name for example 'hello' it should show the related words which are starting from 'he'.

I am new to Python. How can we do this? I have written a function for this.

```
def name_search(self, cr, uid, name, args=None, operator='ilike', context=None, limit=100):
        if not args:
            args = []
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        ids = []
        name = name + '%'
        cr.execute("select name from learner_info where name like %s", (name,))
        ids = cr.dictfetchall()
        return self.name_get(cr, uid, ids, context)
```

How to call this function in field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to code autocompletion in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821661/how-to-code-autocompletion-in-python)

Comment: What's the bigger picture? Does this function succeed in isolation?

Comment: no, is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the following code a little:

```
# this is just for demonstration purposes, for large sets this will blow up quickly

# "element" is comprised of a character [0], special item (id here) [1], next list [2]

class Root():
    root = []
```

Here you could read in your table data.
I just used a plain text file for convenience.
Name refers to the string you want to suggest whereas id is your row's id.

```
    # read names from file
    def __init__(self, fname):

        with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                name, id = line.split(" ")
                self.add(name, int(id))

    def add(self, name, item):
        current = self.root
        last = None

        # for every character of string traverse the list
        for character in name:
            has = False

            # for every character in current list compare character
            for element in current:
                last = element

                if element[0] == character:
                    current = element[2]
                    has = True
                    break

            if not has:
                current.append([character, None, []])
                last = current[-1]
                current = current[-1][2]
```

We are at the end of the string, add the id.

```
        if last is not None:
            last[1] = item

    def delete(self):
        pass # dunno if you need that =)

    def traverse(self, node=root, partial=""):
        list = []

        for element in node:
            if element[1] is not None:
                print ("%s%s = %s" % (partial, element[0], element[1]))
                list.append([partial+element[0], element[1]])
            if len(element[2]) > 0:
                list += self.traverse(element[2], partial+element[0])

        return list

    def lookup(self, partial):
        print ("\nlooking up matches for \"%s%%\":" % (partial))
        current = self.root
        counter = 0

        # for every character of string traverse
        for character in partial:

            # for every character in current list compare character
            for element in current:
                if element[0] == character:
                    current = element[2]
                    counter += 1
                    break

        if counter == len(partial):
            print (self.traverse(current, partial))

def test():
    root = Root("names.txt")
    root.traverse()
    root.lookup("ro")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

I used the following names.txt:

michael 1

mick 2

miquel 3

bla 5

rodrigo 2

rosquez 51

roberto 13

rosquin 1111