# Pyreadline arbitrary autocomplete on windows

Tags: python, windows, autocomplete, readline

I am trying to implement an arbitrary autocomplete on windows for a command-line user interface I am writing. Inspired by the first answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821661/how-to-code-autocompletion-in-python/7821956), I tried to just run the script written there, before realizing that I was on Windows and needed to use `pyreadline` instead of `readline`. After some trials I ended up with the script below, which is basically a copy-paste, but with pyreader initialization:

```
from pyreadline import Readline

readline = Readline()

class MyCompleter(object):  # Custom completer

    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = sorted(options)

    def complete(self, text, state):
        if state == 0:  # on first trigger, build possible matches
            if text:  # cache matches (entries that start with entered text)
                self.matches = [s for s in self.options
                                    if s and s.startswith(text)]
            else:  # no text entered, all matches possible
                self.matches = self.options[:]

        # return match indexed by state
        try:

            return self.matches[state]
        except IndexError:
            return None

completer = MyCompleter(["hello", "hi", "how are you", "goodbye", "great"])
readline.set_completer(completer.complete)
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')

input = raw_input("Input: ")
print "You entered", input
```

The problem is however when I try to run that script, `<TAB>` does not lead to autocomplete.

How do I get `<TAB>` to perform the autocompletion behavior?

Initially I though I messed up the completer setting and binding initialization that would be different for `pyreadeline` compared to `readline`, but from module code and examples in `pyreadline` docs it looks they are identical.

I am trying to execute it on 2.7 Anaconda Python distribution in Windows 10, if this is of any use.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same problem (even with `pyreadline` completion does not work on Windows) I stumbled upon a [blog post](https://opensource.com/article/17/5/4-practical-python-libraries) introducing some Python libraries. After reading I started using the [Python Prompt Toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit) to add the [completion feature](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/asking_for_input.html#autocompletion) to my script.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed. Just gotta rewrite half my app :P